# Given a (n,3) array how to obtain a list of 3 (n,1)-arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array like:

```py
import numpy as np

np.array([[0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 1]])
```

here has shape (2,3) but it can be (n,3). I would like to transform it in a list of arrays representing columns.

**Desired Output**

```py
[array([[0],[1]]), array([[0],[1]]), array([[0],[1]])]
```

I tried list comprehension, reshape etc. but I do not manage to get there.

Comment: try using the `zip()` built-in. You can unpack the list like this: `zip(*array)`

Comment: Must this be in base Python? If you're doing any serious array work, use `numpy`, where arrays have a [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html?highlight=array%20transpose#numpy.ndarray.transpose) method, or else just write the shorthand `array.T`

Comment: `[array([[0],[1]]), array([[0],[1]]), array([[0],[1]])]` shape is `(3,2,1)`. You want 3-D array as output?

Comment: @Ch3steR No, I want a list of three arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehensions you have 2 options:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1]])
[c for c in a.T]
[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])]

[a[:,i] for i in range(a.shape[1])]
[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])]

#or as hpaulj suggested in the comment
[a[:,[i]] for i in range(a.shape[1])]
[array([[0],[1]]),
 array([[0],[1]]),
 array([[0],[1]])]
```

Comment: `[a[:,[i]]` would give the (2,1) array shape the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy hsplit() function like this:

```
>>> a=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
...        [1, 1, 1]])

>>> b,c,d = np.hsplit(a,3)
>>> b
array([[0],
       [1]])
>>> c
array([[0],
       [1]])
>>> d
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

To make it a single list of three arrays:

```
>>> myList = [*np.hsplit(a,3)]
>>> myList
[array([[0],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [1]]), array([[0],
       [1]])]
```